# coursier launch scala 3.1.0

Tags: scala, coursier

How to launch scala 3.1.0 using coursier?

I tried and got this ...

```
~ cs launch scala:3.1.0
Resolution error: Error downloading org.scala-lang:scala-compiler:3.1.0
  not found: /Users/bh/.ivy2/local/org.scala-lang/scala-compiler/3.1.0/ivys/ivy.xml
  not found: https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/scala-lang/scala-compiler/3.1.0/scala-compiler-3.1.0.pom
```

I tried `cs fetch ...` to help the above go through but it is not helping.

Can someone help me with the complete `cs fetch ...` command?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with:

```
./cs launch scala3:3.1.0
```

It should work.
You should use `scala` only for Scala 2 versions.